# Backbone js with JSONP 

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a simple backbone application, which has struts controller as its backend and it was working fine. Then I tried to include cross domain request handling logic and I came to know that there are 2 ways to make cross domain request

1. JSONP
2. CORS

Now what I'm trying to do is, if the browser is not supporting CORS.. Then I'll have to make JSONP request. I'm done with CORS (just added header using filter) and this part is working, but I'm not able to make JSONP request successfully.

My questions regarding this are:

1. What should be the response from server (struts controller) be? Does it return something like function call? As of now it is returning model.
2. In Backbone js, overriding only the Backbone.sync to have its datatype as JSONP is enough?

Note: I'm getting the following error for my JSONP call:

> Error: jsonpCallback was not called

Code: I overrided my sync in collection. My Sync function is

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {             
        options.dataType = 'jsonp';
        options.url="http://localhost:8084/CrossDomain_backbone/messages.json";           
        //options.contentType='application/json-p';
        options.error=this.errorr;
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
   ,
    parse: function(resp){
        alert('inside parse..');
        return resp.model;
    },
    errorr:function(response,responseText)
    {
        alert('inside callback..: ' + responseText);
    },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your Struts code will need to return a function call which contains the data.

The url request might look something like this:

```
options.url="http://localhost:8084/CrossDomain_backbone/messages.json?callback=?";
```

The `callback` part of the query string will automatically be substituted with a random function name that your Struts code will need to use.

For example, when the JSONP request is made, jQuery (used by Backbone) might look like this:

```
http://localhost:8084/CrossDomain_backbone/messages.json?callback=jQuery17205394351207651198_1336231056100
```

So, your Struts code will read the callback parameter and emit JavaScript something like this:

```
jQuery17205394351207651198_1336231056100({
    "name": "Henry T Ford",
    "company": "Ford Motor Company",
    "modified": "2012-04-05T15:06:36Z"});
```

jQuery handles creating a temporary function with that random name to receive the response and pass it to the defined success method.